# Unorthodox use of html5 nav tag

Tags: html, nav, semantic-markup

I have  made "creative" use of the new html5 elements, sometimes pushing the intended boundaries a bit.

Like most, my site is mainly made of articles comments and links to other articles. I decided that I'd use the article tag just once, so there's no confusion whatsoever. For comments, I'm using the aside element and I think that it fits the definition - it's related to the content but it can be done without.

In the case of links to other articles (actually, titles with excerpts and taxonomy aids), I've decided to just use the nav, for lack of a better element, and I know that this is where it becomes tricky. Normally, nav is intended as a list of links for the main navigation. Well, clicking on related posts actually is the primary means of navigation on my site (and most web 2.0 sites). They're also a "list" of links, as beside the main link they also contain a link to the category listing, one to the author's other posts and one to the date-based archive.

The issue is that there are 10+ such navs on each page (can't wrap them in the same nav as they're not all consecutive), which was probably not intended by spec authors - or was it?

The code validates just fine and sectioning makes sense as well, but I wonder if there still are any practical consequences to this. I don't want the site to be a nuissance to screen reader users, for example (otoh, if it's no nuissance, I wouldn't want to cater for a problem that doesn't exist either). So what is the worst that could happen?

Comment: HTML5 spec says about the `nav` element, _“the element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major navigation blocks”_ – note that it says sections and major navigation blocks – plural. Nothing says that there must be only one `nav` element on a page; and if those links to other articles _are_ the main way of navigating around your site (and structured in a way that makes sense for that purpose), then I don’t see any problem with that.

Comment: _“I decided that I'd use the article tag just once”_ – you mean, even if the page consists of multiple articles, you are using `article` just for one of them, and different markup for the rest? That however would not make much sense IMHO.

Comment: It doesn't consist of multiple articles (if it did i'd use it multiple times of course), what I see as "article" consists of the main story or post. There were questions suggesting that comments or even excerpts may belong in an `article` as well, that's why I even brought this up.

Comment: If each page contains one article only, then how come that _“there are 10+ such navs on each page”_ – are you talking about what you defined as the “main” navigation, that contains the links to related articles here? If so, why do those need to be split up?

Comment: There's a main story, the 'article' and there there are a bunch of related links - the 'nav's. They are split up because they're not all in the same place - some are before the article (in same category), some after (previous/next), some on the sidebar alternating with other elements etc.

Comment: Well, two single links to the previous and next article are rather not a “major navigation block”, so I would probably not use `nav` for those.

Comment: Each excerpt, including that of the previous or next post, is a block with the same standard structure, consisting of linked category title, then thumbnail, followed by linked post title then linked author name then text snippet and then link to date-based archive. So right now, for the prev/next I use two navs of 4 links each.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only thing that could happen is that web crawlers (such as googlebot) will treat those as navigation sections. what the actual meaning of this we could only tell if someone from google will reveal to us some secrets...

**Things to consider:**

Reading the nav tag specs:

> Browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use this
>   element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of this
>   content.

for article the specs says:

> An article should make sense on its own, and it should be possible to read it
>   independently from the rest of the web site.
>
> Examples of where an  element can be used:
>
> Forum post Blog post Newspaper article

So.. If it was me I would put the whole thing (all articles) inside `<main></main>` tag and create separate `<article>` for each article. for the comments I would use `<aside>` too, also for the links I would use `<nav>` just like you did, but maybe someone else have better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following the HTML5 specification allows various user agents to "present and use documents and applications in a wide variety of contexts that the author might not have considered." ([HTML5, *Semantics*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#semantics-0)).

If you’re not using the most specific elements available, or if you’re using elements not according to their definitions, it’s possible that some user agents fail to do whatever their job is.

If these are "practical consequences" for you can’t be answered, because it depends on what you care about, and on which user agents do and will consume your documents (which is impossible to know).

For example:

- The [`article` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element) is defined to represent, among other compositions, a "user-submitted comment".
  The spec even explicitly mentions the case for a blog post’s comments, which could be represented "as `article` elements nested within the `article` element for the blog entry."

  It is conceivable that, for example, a comment-processing user agent will look for (or even depend on) this markup.

  And by not following the spec here (not using `article` for comments), you can’t use other features of HTML5, or its extensions, that are based on using appropriate elements. For example, if you’d nest your `aside` elements (representing the comments) in the `article` (which should be done, as they are related to the `article`, not the whole document):

  - You could not use the [`address` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-address-element) for providing the `article` author’s contact information. If you’d use `article` (as intended), each one (this means, the original post as well as each comment) could have its own `address`.
  - You could not use the [`author` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-author) for the commenting user’s website, as this applies to the "nearest `article` element ancestor" (so the commenting users would be considered authors of your post).
- While using the [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-nav-element) for "related links" is not wrong (its actual definition is pretty broad), I think it’s counterproductive to do this.

  If the links are related to the `article`, they should be nested in this `article`. Using `nav` here would convey the wrong meaning: it’s not the navigation for this `article`, right? Instead of `nav`, here using the [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-aside-element) seems to be appropriate.

  For sites that don’t have a classical menu, the pagination is typically the primary navigation.

  And think for example about screen reader users: they might use a feature to jump to the page’s navigation (e.g., to get an overview of the site, to learn what is available). Even ignoring the fact that having multiple, scattered `nav` elements might make this harder, how useful would it be to listen to a list of a few (not even all) post titles, which are typically longer than what’s ideal for a site navigation? And on top of that, this navigation likely even changes from page to page, so the users would have to do it again and again, skipping through possibly many duplicates.

**tl;dr**: Unless you have very good reasons, follow the definitions from the spec. Better use meaningless elements (`div`, `span`, in some cases `section`, etc.) instead of "reinterpretting" other elements which you can’t use according to their defined meaning or their intended purpose.

Comment: I thought that navigation would be skipped rather than skipped to, as in the latter case it's exactly the intended user behaviour... finished reading and see what else we've got. If the nav is meant to be constant all through the site for the sake predictibility, then yes - that's a good point, but it's not in the spec,â. They better put it there so user agents themselves know what to look for.
I'm doing my best to follow the defs, but don't want to "leave money on the table" either, that's why I'm asking. Sure, divs are always good, but it hurts to just throw away hours of documentation ;)